# Web scraping from remax.com

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some data from Remax.com for information like lotsize or square feet of property. Although I am get the following errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname)
    440             try:
--> 441                 cnx.do_handshake()
    442             except OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py in do_handshake(self)
   1715         result = _lib.SSL_do_handshake(self._ssl)
-> 1716         self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
   1717 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py in _raise_ssl_error(self, ssl, result)
   1455         else:
-> 1456             _raise_current_error()
   1457 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py in exception_from_error_queue(exception_type)
     53 
---> 54     raise exception_type(errors)
     55 

Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    600                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 601                                                   chunked=chunked)
    602 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    345         try:
--> 346             self._validate_conn(conn)
    347         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
    849         if not getattr(conn, 'sock', None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
--> 850             conn.connect()
    851 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    325             server_hostname=hostname,
--> 326             ssl_context=context)
    327 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir)
    328     if HAS_SNI:  # Platform-specific: OpenSSL with enabled SNI
--> 329         return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
    330 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname)
    447             except OpenSSL.SSL.Error as e:
--> 448                 raise ssl.SSLError('bad handshake: %r' % e)
    449             break

SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    439                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 440                     timeout=timeout
    441                 )

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    638             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 639                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    640             retries.sleep()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    387         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 388             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    389 

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.remax.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/listings?nwlat=33.8426971435546875&nwlong=-118.3811187744140625&selat=33.8426971435546875&selong=-118.3783721923828125&Count=100&pagenumber=1&SiteID=68000000&pageCount=10&tab=map&sh=true&forcelatlong=true&maplistings=1&maplistcards=0&sv=true&sortorder=newest&view=forsale (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-bcfdfdfb0a4e> in <module>()
----> 1 get_info('119 S IRENA AVE B, Redondo Beach, CA 90277')

<ipython-input-21-f3c942a87400> in get_info(address)
     32         }
     33 #         proxies = {'http': 'http://user:pass@10.10.1.10:3128/'}
---> 34         req_properties = requests.get("https://www.remax.com/api/listings", params=params)
     35         matching_properties_json = req_properties.json()
     36         for p in matching_properties_json[0]:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     70 
     71     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 72     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     73 
     74 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     56     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     57     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 58         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     59 
     60 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    506         }
    507         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 508         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    509 
    510         return resp

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    616 
    617         # Send the request
--> 618         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    619 
    620         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    504             if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
    505                 # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
--> 506                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    507 
    508             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.remax.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/listings?nwlat=33.8426971435546875&nwlong=-118.3811187744140625&selat=33.8426971435546875&selong=-118.3783721923828125&Count=100&pagenumber=1&SiteID=68000000&pageCount=10&tab=map&sh=true&forcelatlong=true&maplistings=1&maplistcards=0&sv=true&sortorder=newest&view=forsale (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

Here is my code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import geolib
from geolib import geohash
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter
import requests

geolocator = Nominatim(timeout=None)
def get_dir(address):
    location = geolocator.geocode(address)
    lat = location.latitude
    lng = location.longitude
    h = geolib.geohash.encode(lat, lng, 7)
    hashes = geolib.geohash.neighbours(h)
    NW = geohash.decode(hashes.nw)
    SE = geohash.decode(hashes.ne)
    nwlat = NW.lat
    nwlon = NW.lon
    selat = SE.lat
    selon = SE.lon
    return nwlat, nwlon, selat, selon

    def get_info(address):
    try:
        nwlat, nwlon, selat, selon = get_dir(address)
        params = {
        "nwlat" : nwlat,        
        "nwlong" : nwlon,     
        "selat" : selat,     
        "selong" : selon,   
        "Count" : 100,
        "pagenumber" : 1,
        "SiteID" : "68000000",
        "pageCount" : "10",
        "tab" : "map",
        "sh" : "true",
        "forcelatlong" : "true",
        "maplistings" : "1",
        "maplistcards" : "0",
        "sv" : "true",
        "sortorder" : "newest",
        "view" : "homeestimates",
        }
        proxies = {'http': 'http://user:pass@10.10.1.10:3128/'}
        req_properties = requests.get("https://www.remax.com/api/listings", params=params, proxies=proxies, verify=False)
        matching_properties_json = req_properties.json()
        for p in matching_properties_json[0]:
            print(f"{p['Address']:<40}  {p.get('BedRooms', 0)} beds | {int(p.get('BathRooms',0))} baths | {p['SqFt']} sqft")
    except (AttributeError):
        return 'NaN'

x = get_info('693 Bluebird Canyon Drive, Laguna Beach CA, 92651')
print(x)
```

I am not sure how to fix this problem as I am new to web scraping, I tried adding a proxy in the code but I still get the same errors in the latter above.

**Update:**

adding

```
proxies = {'http': 'http://user:pass@10.10.1.10:3128/'}
req_properties = requests.get("https://www.remax.com/api/listings", params=params, proxies=proxies, verify=False)
```

yields no errors but also no output at all.

Comment: are you using a proxy ?

Comment: @NipunWijerathne I do not believe so, how would I know?

Comment: Take a look at this answer which pertains to the error you are getting - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-sslerror

Comment: @Bert I tried following the suggestions but still doesn't solve the problem but thank you for the comment.

Comment: Does the code in the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54914950/4985733) return results for you? If so the issue should not be proxy related.

Comment: @MartinEvans It does work but I need lotsize as well. Also, it doesn't seem to work in the case I provided where I don't hardcode the lat and longitude information

Comment: My apologies if I'm asking a non-relevant question, but Is it even legal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appear to be a number of issues:

1. Proxy is not an issue as you have said the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54914950/4985733) is working without needing one to be configured.
2. Your `geohash.decode(hashes.ne)` call is using `ne` instead of `se`.
3. The returned coordinates are not returning any valid properties, the API appears to return a different kind of response in this case which does not include the values you want. It does include the price though.
4. Make sure that `verify=False` is configured for the get. The warning message can be suppressed.

If the search square is increased slightly in size, it does return results:

```
import urllib
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import geolib
from geolib import geohash
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter
import requests


# Disable the certificate warning
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
geolocator = Nominatim(timeout=None)


def get_dir(address):
    location = geolocator.geocode(address)
    lat = location.latitude
    lng = location.longitude
    h = geolib.geohash.encode(lat, lng, 7)
    hashes = geolib.geohash.neighbours(h)
    NW = geohash.decode(hashes.nw)
    SE = geohash.decode(hashes.se)

    return NW, SE


def get_info(address):
    try:
        NW, SE = get_dir(address)
        square_size = 0.001

        params = {
            "nwlat" : float(NW.lat) + square_size,        
            "nwlong" : float(NW.lon) - square_size,
            "selat" : float(SE.lat) - square_size,
            "selong" : float(SE.lon) + square_size,   
            "Count" : 100,
            "pagenumber" : 1,
            "SiteID" : "68000000",
            "pageCount" : "10",
            "tab" : "map",
            "sh" : "true",
            "forcelatlong" : "true",
            "maplistings" : "1",
            "maplistcards" : "0",
            "sv" : "true",
            "sortorder" : "newest",
            "view" : "homeestimates",
        }

        req_properties = requests.get("https://www.remax.com/api/listings", params=params, verify=False)
        matching_properties_json = req_properties.json()

        for p in matching_properties_json[0]:
            address = f"{p['Address']}, {p['City']}, {p['State']}, {p['Zip']}"

            try:
                print(f"  {address:<50} | {p.get('BedRooms', 0)} beds | {int(p.get('BathRooms',0))} baths | {p['SqFt']} sqft")
            except KeyError:
                print(f"None found - {address} - ${p['PriceFormatted']}")

    except (AttributeError):
        return 'NaN'

get_info('693 Bluebird Canyon Drive, Laguna Beach CA, 92651')
```

This displays:

```
  1566 Glenneyre Street, Laguna Beach, CA, 92651     | 0 beds | 0 baths |  sqft
  1585 S Coast 4, Laguna Beach, CA, 92651            | 3 beds | 2 baths | 1448 sqft
  429 Shadow Lane, Laguna Beach, CA, 92651           | 2 beds | 2 baths | 1102 sqft
  243 Calliope Street 1, Laguna Beach, CA, 92651     | 2 beds | 2 baths | 1350 sqft
```

Comment: I get this None found - 1566 Glenneyre Street, Laguna Beach, CA, 92651 - $2,595,000

Comment: set `square_size = 0.001` and try again.

Comment: Perfect, any idea how to get lotsize? I noticed that in the json it doesn't specify lotsize as a name so its difficult to retrieve.

Comment: I suggest you add `print(p)`. You can then see all of the available data for each property. I could only size `SqFt`.

Comment: Thanks for you help, really appreciate it.